# Teaching load and hired by the hour in the Swedish academic system

Tags: teaching, terminology, sweden

I've been offered a teaching position for the Spring semester at a Swedish University. The teaching load is 220 hours and they suggested that I should be hired by the hour.

1. Does any of you know how much do 220 hours mean in terms of a full teaching load for a Universitetlektor?
2. Is there a difference in payment related to the "by the hour system"?

Comment: I think your questions should be directed to the Swedish University who offered you the job.

Comment: You right! I misunderstood the requirements of filling the empty field. I thought I was supposed to fill in my title.

Comment: For scaaahu: Of course I will clarify this with them. I am just trying to make a clearer picture from  multiple sources.

Comment: I have to disagree with the close votes, at it's current form (rev. 5 by Massimo Ortolano) I think the question is valid and in-scope for the site.

Comment: "Hiring by the hour" sounds a bit suspicious, and is in my experience not the usual way to do it. What is your subject area?

Comment: @posdef I agree with posdef: I think this question should not be closed unless somebody who actually knows Sweden says this is too localized: this may be standard practices for Sweden that those of us who don't know its academic system just don't know about.

Comment: @mrf i believe the "hired by the hour" here means that he'll be paid by the hour, instead of a fix monthly salary. But again 220 times X is still a monthly salary. It's possible that there's a misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: This might be more appropriate for http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/, who might know more about how a "by the hour" system works in Sweden.

Comment: Thank you all for comments, answers and insight. I've been talking to the person in charge there and things are like this: it is a temp job, those 220 hours are so-called "semester hours" which consist of 23 hours of physical teaching in classroom, 40 hours of teaching online (on a virtual platform) and the rest of the hours are dedicated to preparation, paper supervision and exams.

Comment: @Marius Could you write that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I've been teaching at a Swedish University, for many years.  When they allocate you 220 hours, they normally mean that it's kind of like a fixed contract.  They normally don't micro-manage you and you'll be paid for 220 hours (if you work a bit more or a bit less), whereas a full-time year is about 1740 hours.

However, they told you the work would be paid hourly, so in your case, it seems that you can work up to 220 allocated hours, and you'll be paid for just how many hours you work.  A trick is, when you see that the work will take more hours, if you can document a really good reason, they may or may not allocate more hours.